# Проблема с таксономиями

Tags: wordpress

Есть такой фал таксономии, замысел был выводить поочередно дочерние таксономии в каждой из категорий, но он выводит все существующие дочерние таксономии в любой из родительских (не только для которой является дочерней), как это исправить? И скрыть родительские объекты, которые уже выведены.

```html
<?
    $taxonomy = get_queried_object(); //Массив текущей таксономии
    $taxonomy_id = 'category_' . $taxonomy->term_id; // Текущий ID таксономии
    $taxonomy_link = get_term_link($taxonomy->term_id); //Ссылка на текущюю категорию
    $terms = get_terms( array(
 'taxonomy'      => array('post_tag', 'product_subcategories' ), // название таксономии с WP 4.5
 'orderby'       => 'id', 
 'order'         => 'ASC',
 'hide_empty'    => true, 
 'object_ids'    => null,
 'include'       => array(),
 'exclude'       => array(), 
 'exclude_tree'  => array(), 
 'number'        => '', 
 'fields'        => 'all', 
 'count'         => false,
 'slug'          => '', 
 'parent'         => '',
 'hierarchical'  => true, 
 'child_of'      => 0, 
 'get'           => '', // ставим all чтобы получить все термины
 'name__like'    => '',
 'pad_counts'    => false, 
 'offset'        => '', 
 'search'        => '', 
 'cache_domain'  => 'core',
 'name'          => '',    // str/arr поле name для получения термина по нему. C 4.2.
 'childless'     => false, // true не получит (пропустит) термины у которых есть дочерние термины. C 4.2.
 'update_term_meta_cache' => true, // подгружать метаданные в кэш
 'meta_query'    => '',
) );

?>

 <div class="content">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="products category">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="description">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h2><? echo $taxonomy->name; ?></h2>
                        <p><? echo $taxonomy->description; ?></p>
                        
                    </div>
                    
               </div>
<?php
$term_slug = get_query_var('term');
$taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$term_args = array('parent' => 0, 'orderby'=>'id', 'order'=>'ASC', 'hide_empty'=>false, );
$get_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $term_args);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array( 'child_of' => $term_id ) );
foreach($get_terms as $parent) :

?>
<?php
$parent_id = $parent->term_id; //Store the category ID as a variable to be used in WP_Query

$term_children = get_term_children( $parent_id, $taxonomy );
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy );
$child_id = $term->term_id;
echo '<h3><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></h3>';

$args = array(
'post_type' => $post_type,
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
'field' => 'id',
'terms' => $child_id,
),
),
);

$wpq = new WP_Query($args);
echo '<ul>';
if($wpq->have_posts()) {
while ( $wpq->have_posts() ) : $wpq->the_post();$gallery = get_field('image_gallery', get_the_ID() );
?>
    <li>
         <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">
            <span class="photo"><img src="<? echo $gallery[0]; //Первое изображение из массива галереи ?>"/></span>
            <p class="description"><? the_title(); ?></p>

        </a>
    </li>
<?php
endwhile;
}//have_posts
echo '</ul>';
}//term_children
}
?>
<?php
endforeach;
?>




                <ul>
                    

                    <? while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // Выводим товары текущей рубрик
                    
                        $gallery = get_field('image_gallery', get_the_ID() ); //Массив изображений
                        
                    ?>

                        <li>
                            <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <span class="photo"><img src="<? echo $gallery[0]; //Первое изображение из массива галереи ?>"/></span>
                                <p class="description"><? the_title(); ?></p>

                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <? endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код ужасен. Чтобы получить дочерние категории какой-то определеной используйте код:

```
$terms = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy',
    'parent'   => $term_id,
] );
```